# UNIX sockets::recv, std::byte, and strict aliasing

Tags: c++, sockets, c++20, strict-aliasing, address-sanitizer

I'm writing a function that basically wraps `recv`:

```
ssize_t recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
```

In particular, I want to write to receive some bytes; and sometimes these bytes will be part of an ASCII string, other times they will be integers, or maybe just plain "bytes" that are part of some higher-level protocol.

I thought that maybe the right way to abstract this in modern C++ would be to write to a `std::byte` buffer, so maybe something like this

```
std::vector<std::byte> buffer;
buffer.resize(100);
recv(socket, buffer.data(), 100, /* flags = */ 0);
```

My first question is: are there any issues with writing to a "buffer" of `std::byte`s as above? Should the buffer be of type `std::vector<char>` instead? I guess this is fine but I'm not 100% sure.

My second question is the following: say that now I want to treat `buffer` as a string. The code

```
std::string str(buffer.data(), 100);
```

fails because `std::byte*` does not convert to `const char*`, and I'm almost sure that

```
std::string str(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer.data()), 100);
```

is undefined behavior because of the strict aliasing rule.

Is the only way to due this with something like `memcpy`:

```
std::string ret;
ret.resize(100);
std::memcpy(ret.data(), buffer.data(), 100);
```

?

What if I want a `std::string_view`? Can I make a `std::string_view` of `buffer` without actually copying the bytes to some intermediate place first? Could `std::bit_cast` work?

Interestingly, clang does not complain about something similar to the `std::string(reinterpret_cast...` solution: https://godbolt.org/z/7zshhr (even compiling with `-fsanitize=address` or `-fsanitize=undefined`)

Comment: Just remember that `recv` can and will return a number of bytes less than requested. So prepare to resize your buffer after checking the return result.  Or use the MSG_WAITALL flag - but you still have to handle getting less than the number of bytes expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between a `char` and a `byte`, in this instance. In fact, originally these network functions were defined in terms of the `char` data type. A very long time ago the second parameter to `recv` was a `char *`, instead of a `void *` as it is now.

This would make converting the `std::vector<char>` into a `std::string` a nothing-burger. You may even choose to forego `std::vector<char>` entirely. You can resize your `std::string` up-front, then `recv()` directly into it, then resize it again according to how many bytes were received.

Comment: There are differences between these types, but there are specific rules about aliasing that allow this case.